# Convert file names inside ZIP archive in Python

Tags: python, zip

Is it possible to rename files inside folders of a zip archive using python? I have this zip downloaded from [here](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-config-resource-schema), but file names contain ::, so Windows doesn't like it. Simple .replace('::','-') on it would make my day

Answer (score 0):

just loop through the archive and write the files out as whatever you want them to be called

```
    with zipfile.ZipFile(filename, "r") as zf:
        extracted_names = zf.namelist()
        for name in extracted_names:
            new_filename = name.replace('::', '')
            with open(new_filename, 'wb') as f:
                f.write(zf.read(name))
```